# How to set a dict value using another key of the same dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to do something like this:

```
my_dict = {"key": "value", "key1": "value1", "key2": my_dict["key"]}
```

and have the result be:

```
{"key": "value", "key1": "value1", "key2": "value"}
```

Currently getting unresolved reference unless I declare the dict() prior. Otherwise I get a key error.

Comment: `my_dict = {"key": "value", "key1": "value1"}; my_dict["key2"] = my_dict["key"]` bam

Comment: Well, your dict is not initialized, you cannot reference something that doesn't yet exist. You can use `lambda` to dynamically call your keys if you want to create a self-referencing dictionary.

Comment: @Nicolas, the problem is that assignment statements are evaluated right to left, so `my_dict` is not defined yet though you are defining it in this line.

Comment: @zwer how, exactly?

Comment: Split up the items being added so that they are defined before you try to back-reference them, like this (shown here on one line b/c Stack Overflow does not support formatting in Comments):  my_dict = {}  ;  my_dict['key']  = 'value'  ; 
 my_dict['key1'] = 'value1'  ;  my_dict['key2'] = my_dict['key']

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the value of `key2` to something phony (say, `None`), initialize `my_dict` properly, and then change the value of `my_dict['key2']` to `my_dict["key"]`.